# Como executar uma função cujo nome está no banco de dados?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, html5, ajax

Gostaria de saber como executar uma função em JavaScript pegando seu nome no banco de dados. Exemplo:

```
data["nome_coluna"] // essa será a informação que estará no banco. (exemplo: somar();)

// Aí o objetivo é executar essa função dentro de um if.

if(data["nome_coluna"] != ""){
    data["nome_coluna"];
}
```

Existe uma forma de fazer isso? Essa forma é errada? Se sim, como fazer?

OBS: O objetivo disso é fazer que quando eu compre uma carta e ela tiver uma função que deve acontecer de forma imediata, então chame a função que está salva no banco de dados. Como são muitas cartas, não é viável ficar fazendo um if para cada carta, já que são funções diferentes.

Comment: Somente o nome da função. Preciso chamar ela dentro do if, só que vai chamar a função da carta em especifico.

Comment: Atualmente esta com parenteses. mas isso é tranquilo de mudar, caso funcione sem.

Comment: De qualquer forma vc vai ter que ter na página o código de todas as funções.

Comment: O código sim, mas fica mais fácil eu chamar a função direto do banco e fazer apenas um if, do que ficar verificando qual carta é e chamando a função.

Comment: Tenta assim, mas apenas se o nome da função vier sem os parênteses: `if(window[data["nome_coluna"]]){
    window[data["nome_coluna"]]();
}`

Comment: Cara, funcionou!!! Muito obrigado, o que esse window faz?

Comment: Ele pega as variáveis globais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar se a função existe antes de tentar executá-la. Mas para isso a função deve ter escopo global para chamá-la com o objeto `window`:

```
if(window[data["nome_coluna"]]){
    window[data["nome_coluna"]]();
}
```

Neste caso o nome da função deve vir sem os `()` na variável `data["nome_coluna"]`. O objeto `window` possui como propriedades as funções criadas na página com escopo global (pode ter uma noção de escopo [nesta documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Para poder fazer isso você poderá criar uma **classe** e usar da seguinte maneira;

Se ela estiver em seu **arquivo** ou devidamente **importada**, você pode chamar assim `minhaClasse.['nome_coluna']()` ou `this.['nome_coluna']()`, vai depender do contexto.

Usando o seu exemplo e considerando que está vindo do banco **sem** os `()`:

```
data["nome_coluna"] 

if(data["nome_coluna"] != ""){
    minhaClasse.[data["nome_coluna"]](); // Ou como eu disse
    // minhaClasse.[this.data["nome_coluna"]](); // Não sei o seu contexto
}
```

Acredito que assim rode.

Tem a maneira que o Sam falou acima também, para usar sem classe, `window[data["nome_coluna"]]`, se vier **com** os `()`, e `window[data["nome_coluna"]]()`, se vier **sem** os `()`

Comment: No meu contexto aqui, não funcionou dessa forma! Mas mesmo assim muito obrigado.